# Use contentDocument in electron

Tags: javascript, svg, electron

I need to work with local external SVG files and I also need to get some data from them. It means I need to reach them through the DOM and check its content.

I am using `<object id="svg-object" data="./my_svg.svg"></object>` for the import and here is my code to reach the svg:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      var svgObject = document.getElementById('svg-object').contentDocument;
      var svg = svgObject.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
      console.log(svg);
    });
```

After some research and several fails I found out that is no longer working offline (or maybe I am missing something), It only works when I am on a server.

My question is, how can I get around this, because I want to build and offline application using electron.

Comment: run a local server.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like thats the only way...So If I create a local webserver on port 9000 for example, then ```win.loadURL('htttp://localhost/9000');``` will work?

Comment: Not with that spelling of http